# Setup three if else conditions on Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="App/Deny">
<ItemTemplate>

    <asp:Label ID="lblAppDeny" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("App/Deny").ToString() == "" ? "Paddings" : null + "," + Eval("App/Deny").ToString() == "Approve" ? null : "Approve" + "," + Eval("App/Deny").ToString() == "Deny" ? null : "Deny" %>' CssClass='<%#Eval("App/Deny").ToString() == "" ? "badge warning text-sm" : null + "," + Eval("App/Deny").ToString() == "Approve" ? "badge success text-sm" : null + "," +Eval("App/Deny").ToString() == "Deny" ? null : "badge danger text-sm" %>'>
    </asp:Label>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I need to show three type of value in the column if the String.Empty is available then the value was shown Pending and if the Value is Approve Or Deny then show that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a method on the page the GridView is on to handle the if else codes.

```
public string formatValue(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        return "Empty";
    }
    else if (input == "Pending")
    {
        return "Is pending";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Available";
    }
}
```

In the GridView

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="App/Deny">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# formatValue(Eval("App/Deny").ToString()) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```